# lookup between two dataframes, missing few rows matching value in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a df1 -

```
|id|name| 
|2|op|
|4|kl|
|5|jk|
```

I have another df df2 -

```
|id_no|
|4|
|2|
|5|
|2|
|1|
```

I want to get 'name` from df1 to df2 matching id's.
Used below approach -

```
df2['id_no'] = df2['id_no'].astype('int64')
df1['id'] = df1['id'].astype('int64')

df2['names'] = df2['id_no'].map(df1.set_index('id')['name'])
```

Getting below output -

```
|id_no|names|
|4|kl|
|2|op|
|5|jk|
|2|NAN|
|1|NAN|
```

Its strange that second time id_no 2 is not appending the name from df1. Can someone pls suggest what is the solution to this issue?
Please help.

Comment: Second `2` is not numeric I guess.

Comment: @jezrael, I have done both the conversions df1 and df2 id's to int.

Comment: Any solution , how can we do the conversion of both 2's to int and get the names appended to df2

Comment: If check `print (df2['id_no'].unique())` it return only one `2` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `pd.Series.unique()` - it will only return each value once.

Comment: Why dont you use `merge` method instead of `map` to join the dataframes like so: `pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on='id_no', right_on='id', how='left').drop(columns=["id"])`

Comment: what is u desierd output?  as mentioned, use merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can check unique values for investigate problem, but here if same types it should working correct.:

```
 print (df['id_no'].unique())
```

---

Another idea with left join and `rename` column:

```
df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'id':'id_no'}), on='id_no', how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use the pandas [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) or [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) functions here:

```py
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": [2, 4, 5], "name": ["op", "kl", "jk"]})
>>> df1

   id name
0   2   op
1   4   kl
2   5   jk

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id_no": [4, 2, 5, 2, 1]})
>>> df2

   id_no
0      4
1      2
2      5
3      2
4      1

>>> df2.merge(df1, left_on='id_no', right_on='id', how='outer')

   id_no   id name
0      4  4.0   kl
1      2  2.0   op
2      2  2.0   op
3      5  5.0   jk
4      1  NaN  NaN
```

The column `id` is converted to float so it can hold the `NaN` value, which cannot be expressed in an `int` type.